# xmlel parsing using fxml

Tags: parsing, erlang, fxml, ejabberd

I have a packet like this :

```
[{message,<<"1529424074151_7FEAC332-2AA0-410B-93C1-6A50D73EB91C">>,chat,<<"en">>,{jid,<<"testuser">>,<<"xmpp-qa.myhost.me">>,<<"7FEAC332-2AA0-410B-93C1-6A50D73EB91C">>,<<"testuser">>,<<"xmpp-qa.myhost.me">>,<<"7FEAC332-2AA0-410B-93C1-6A50D73EB91C">>},{jid,<<"testuser2">>,<<"xmpp-qa.myhost.me">>,<<"7FEAC332-2AA0-410B-93C1-6A50D73EB91C">>,<<"testuser2">>,<<"xmpp-qa.myhost.me">>,<<"7FEAC332-2AA0-410B-93C1-6A50D73EB91C">>},[],[{text,<<>>,<<"H\nJ\nK\nL">>}],undefined,[{mam_archived,{jid,<<"testuser2">>,<<"xmpp-qa.myhost.me">>,<<>>,<<"testuser2">>,<<"xmpp-qa.myhost.me">>,<<>>},<<"1529424074316547">>},{stanza_id,{jid,<<"testuser2">>,<<"xmpp-qa.myhost.me">>,<<>>,<<"testuser2">>,<<"xmpp-qa.myhost.me">>,<<>>},<<"1529424074316547">>},{xmlel,<<"message_format">>,[],[{xmlel,<<"messageId">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"1529424074151_7FEAC332-2AA0-410B-93C1-6A50D73EB91C">>}]},{xmlel,<<"messageTime">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"1529424074151">>}]}]},{xmlel,<<"markable">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:chat-markers:0">>}],[]}],#{ip => {10,100,66,249},mam_archived => true,stanza_id => 1529424074316547}}]
```

I want to get the value of "format" inside :

```
{xmlel,<<"format">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"sms">>}]},
```

so here it will be "sms"

Can anyone tell me how to get this value i am using fxml and ejabberd 18.04.
right now i am trying :

```
Temp_format = fxml:get_subtag(Pkt, <<"message_format">>),
```

and :

```
fxml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, "message_format"}])
```

but both are giving me error :

```
** Reason = {error,function_clause,[{fxml,get_subtag,[{file,"src/fxml.erl"},{line,175}],
```

Comment: According of the type signature of `get_subtag`, the first argument should be a `xmlel` record. Are you passing that list as the first argument?

Comment: yes i am passing a list, it is the same list as i have mentioned at the top

Comment: i want to get the read value of "format" that is "sms" in my case.
also as we can see the given document isn't a xmlel.So any workaround ?